# how can I put an edit button in UITable at the end of a cell?

Tags: iphone, cell, uitableview

I want to put a edit button(icon), as most application has in the cell where the value exists???

I want as below output,

Hotel Royal     >
Hotel Taj       >

> shows the button or icon,
>   how can I do it ???

if you don't understand my question, you may ask again .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for the `>` you see at the cells, these are accessoryViews.
You can get the standard accessory views by setting the accessoryType property of the cell

for [image] you use

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

for [image]

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

and for [image]

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

if you use the DetailDisclosure button you can get the taps on it with the tableview delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Is there any size option, because when when it is in "cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
", then hard to click at exact position as compared to "cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;"

Comment: no, if you want a different size you have to create your own view and set the accessoryView of the cell.